# setting a value to the second handle in jquery slider ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slider, handle

I want to set the 2nd handle in my jquery slider to a variable. 
so for example lets just say the variable is "x" my code looks like this

```
function $sliderHandle2(x) {
//set the 2nd handle here
var value = $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "1", "value" );
$( "#slider-range" ).slider( "1","value", x );
}
```

I did this using the API from the website but its not working so i assume its very wrong. I thought the "1" would be the number of the handle .

can anyone tell me what part ive done wrong ? I JUST want to set the second handle

Answer (score 0):

Forgot the API instructions all together and worked it out myself, this changes the value of a handle.

```
$("#slider-range").slider('values',1,x);
```

where 1 is the handle index and x is the vale you want to set it to

Answer (score 0):

And another solution:

```
$("#slider-range").slider({
    animate: "fast",
    min : 0,
    max: 4,
    value: 4,
    values : [0,4], // This is it ...
........
});
```